# Eclipse Google Cloud Tools: Where is Datastore running?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, datastore

When running a Java Google App Engine through Eclipse (with Google Cloud Tools) I can inspect my Datastore through the admin dashboard (localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore).

Is it possible to access the Datastore Rest API? Where would I be able to do that? Is it running on the same port under a different path?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Eclipse is starting up `dev_appserver.py` and with this you can't use Datastore API.

I've never used the Datastore emulator, but that might allow you to use the API.

Another option is to use the live Datastore API for a test GAE project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the port in which the Datastore emulator is listening to calls is by default 8081 and can be [changed with](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/datastore/start) `gcloud beta emulators datastore start --host-port=localhost:8081`

Alternatively, if you want to manually access the Datastore API of your GCP project you can:

- Use the [Datastore Dashboard in the Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities)
- Manually make use of the Datastore API as in [Try this API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/projects/lookup) feature.

Alternatively